# React Native Flatlist overlapping footer?

Tags: react-native, formatting, react-native-flatlist

I'm getting started with React Native and writing an app. The problem I'm having a problem with the layout/styling. This is a simplified version to show my difficulty.

The Flatlist doesn't know where it's bottom is, it is overlapping the `Footer` component. I've messed around with it but can't get it to work properly.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { FlatList, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native'

class Header extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.headerContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.headerText}> </Text>
        <Text style={styles.headerText}>
          This is the page header!
        </Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

class Footer extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.footerContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.footerText}>
          This is the page footer!
        </Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

let myData = [];

for (let i=1; i<=30; i++) {
  myData.push({ key: ('My item ' + i) })
}

export default class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Header />

          <View style={styles.listWrapper}>
            <FlatList
              contentContainerStyle={styles.listContainer}
              data={myData}
              renderItem={({item}) => <Text style={styles.listItem} >{item.key}</Text>}
              contentInset={{top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 50, right: 0}}

            />
          </View>

        <Footer />
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'pink'
  },


  headerContainer: {
    backgroundColor: '#333',
    height: 60,
  },
  headerText: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontSize: 20,
    color: '#999'
  },

  listWrapper: {
    flex: 1
  },
  listContainer: {
    backgroundColor: 'lightblue',
  },
  listItem: {
    color: 'red',
    fontSize: 28
  },


  footerContainer: {
    backgroundColor: '#333',
    position: 'absolute',
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    flex: 1,
    height: 20
  },
  footerText: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontSize: 14,
    color: '#999'
  }
})
```

The only solution I have is to add the prop:

```
ListFooterComponent={<View style={{ height: 20 }} />}
```

to the Flatlist, giving it the same height as the `Footer`, so it would take up that space. That works, but it seems inelegant. Is there a better way to do it, like with the CSS?

Thanx.

Comment: Your Footer don't need `position: absolute`. If you use `flex: 1` for your Footer, it'll equal height with your `listWrapper`.
You should read about flex css first to understand flex property.

Comment: But I don't want the Footer to equal the height of the listWrapper. I want a small fixed height Header at the top, a small fixed height Footer at the bottom and the Flatlist to intelligently take up the rest of the space in between. I have read the RN and flex docs but am not smart enough to figure out how to do it. If you have a clever flex solution, please let me know, but what you are suggesting is not what I want.

Comment: FYI: https://snack.expo.io/@trangcongthanh/flatlist

Comment: Thanks, that works. You statement in the original reply that "If you use flex: 1 for your Footer, it'll equal height with your listWrapper." confused me, but your example cleared it up. I also didn't know about the *Constants* object so thanks for that trick too. Thanks.